# Getting dynamic content of div in File.ReadAllText

Tags: c#, html

I need to export the webpage to PDF for that am reading all the content of that file and writing that content in to the PDF file.

Please refer below dynamic content in div tag

```
 <div ng-app="criteriaApp">
                    <div ng-include src="'@Url.Content("~/template.html")'"></div>
            </div>
```

template.html content will be modified dynamically in jquery and displayed in view.

So whenvever am inpsecting the webpage through developer tools i can able to see the content

like

```
<div ng-app="criteriaApp">
                        <div ng-include src="'@Url.Content("~/template.html")'">
<div>.......</div>
</div>
                </div>
```

but getting the content through **File.ReadAllText** doesn't give original DOM elements. it gives the page source code only (i.e.  getting viewPage Source by right clicking the page)

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

i need to get the dynamic contents of div through above code ?

**Note : File.ReadAllText returns page source code only. not all DOM nodes generated dynamically.**

The dynamic content is there in DOM. how can i get DOM code for particular div in C# ?

how can i acheive this ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

To get the dynamic contents of div through your html code, you need to use a engine like webkit to generate DOM. If you need to export your page as pdf, you should look at [razor pdf](https://github.com/RazorAnt/RazorPDF) or [rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa).